# laravel route not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-routing

my route on a laravel project not working, basically i was working on a project then copied it in another directory , run migration and seeds , then only root route is accessible others route show as not found though its working on my previous project. this is th route file

```
 <?php

Route::get('home', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@index',
));
Route::get('acl', array(
    'as' => 'acl',
    'uses' => 'RolesAndPermssion@index',
));
    //or 
/*Route::any('admin/images/(:any)', array(
    'as' => 'admin_images',
    'uses' => 'admin.images@index',
));*/
Route::get('test',function(){
   //  System::__init();
   // return System::getAll();

   //Role::('')
  $options = array(
'validate_all' => false,
'return_type' => 'both'
);
 return "hello";

//var_dump($allValidations);


});
//use Carbon\Carbon;
Route::get('/', function()
{
  //DB::table('permission_role')->delete();
  //DB::table('permissions')->delete();
 return "hello";
//return "Product is Under Construction";
//printf("Now: %s", Carbon::now());

});

Route::get('error/permission', 'BaseController@NotPermitted');

/**
      UserController Routing Start
*/
Route::get( 'user/create',  array('as' => 'usercreate','uses' => 'UserController@create'));
Route::get( 'user/edit/{id}',array('as' => 'useredit','uses' => 'UserController@edit'));
Route::post( 'user/edit',                 'UserController@update');
Route::post('user/store','UserController@store');
Route::delete('user','UserController@delete');
Route::get('user',array('as' => 'users','uses' => 'UserController@index'));
Route::post('user',array('as' => 'users','uses' => 'UserController@index'));
Route::get( 'login',                  'UserController@login');
Route::post('login',                  'UserController@do_login');
Route::get( 'user/confirm/{code}',         'UserController@confirm');
Route::get( 'user/forgot_password',        'UserController@forgot_password');
Route::post('user/forgot_password',        'UserController@do_forgot_password');
Route::get( 'user/reset_password/{token}', 'UserController@reset_password');
Route::post('user/reset_password',         'UserController@do_reset_password');
Route::get( 'user/logout',                 'UserController@logout');
/**
      UserController Routing End
*/

/**
      RolesAndPermissionController Routing Start
*/
Route::get('roles',array('as' => 'roles','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@indexRoles',));
Route::post('roles',array('as' => 'roles','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@indexRoles',));
Route::get( 'roles/create',  array('as' => 'rolecreate','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@createRole'));
Route::post('roles/store','RolesAndPermissionController@storeRole');
Route::get( 'roles/edit/{id}',array('as' => 'roleedit','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@editRole'));
Route::post( 'roles/edit/{id}',                 'RolesAndPermissionController@updateRole');
Route::delete('roles','RolesAndPermissionController@deleteRoles');

Route::get('permissions',array('as' => 'permissions','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@indexPermissions',));
Route::post('permissions',array('as' => 'permissions','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@indexPermissions',));
Route::delete('permissions',array('as' => 'permissionsdelete','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@deletePermissions',));
Route::get( 'permissions/create',  array('as' => 'permissioncreate','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@createPermission'));
Route::post('permissions/store','RolesAndPermissionController@storePermission');
Route::get( 'permissions/edit/{id}',array('as' => 'permissionedit','uses' => 'RolesAndPermissionController@editPermission'));
Route::post( 'permission/edit/{id}',                 'RolesAndPermissionController@updatePermission');
Route::delete('permissions','RolesAndPermissionController@deletePermissions');

/**
      RolesAndPermissionController Routing Start
*/
```

here is the htaccess file from public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and virtual host conf file is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin blahblah@gmail.com
    ServerName ngo.dev
    #ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ngo/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I can access the route using indes.php/route

Comment: Please add the content of `.htaccess` file

Comment: added htaccess file too i think its same as my another project

Comment: I had problems with the htaccess on new project recently, as an experiment could you try changing the trailing slashes line to `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]` and the final rule line to `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]`?

Comment: @DaveMorrissey not working :(

Comment: Did you manage the alias? Did you assign the `/` access to `/public/`?

Comment: though php artisan routes command shows all route

Comment: where? in virual host conf file yes i did @AlaaBadran

Comment: yes, in your Apache virtual hosts

Comment: Ok, sorry that didn't help. You can add rewrite logging with `RewriteLog "/path/to/rewrite_log" RewriteLogLevel 9` which may help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: 1) Try to remove the `.htaccess` file. 2) If it didn't work, try to access `/public/home` or any route. Let's see if this work

Comment: Start with the basics: did you a) create/update the Apache virtual host? b) enable the new virtual host? c) restart/reload the Apache config?

Comment: @AlaaBadran  accessing public/home not working

Comment: @Kryten yes i did all the things several time with change the config

Comment: @Fisherman try this: `/public/index.php/home` does it work?

Comment: I'd recommend putting the rewrite rules inside your `VirtualHost` directive and deleting the .htaccess file.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey add Rewrteilog not log in i tried in htaccess

Comment: @AlaaBadran tried your link with/without htaccess not working

Comment: Then remove the `.htaccess` and make sure the virtual host is correct. I prefer to write new virtual host alias

Comment: @DaveMorrissey tried too move htaccess rule on conf shows bad request and while accessing index says has a redirect loop

Comment: so how come its working for another project beside it with same configuration on virtual host/ htaccess and route ? i don't know its now two hour i am trying to get rid off it :O

Comment: oh gosh with /index.php/user its working so where i need to change ?

Comment: @Fisherman Have you checked if you set the `AllowOverride All` in apache.conf?

Comment: yes its on @lozadaOmr

Comment: I had a similar issue and had to run `php artisan route:clear` to clear cached routes ..

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem...

In my case, the problem was my .htaccess file, probably the editor on Windows left some weird characters, so I just rewrite the entire file again, and now it's working!